# Google Chrome doesn't keep my "allow all cookies" setting

Tags: linux, google-chrome

It seems that Google Chrome doesn't keep my "allow all cookies" settings (dev 5.0.322.2) anymore.

Google's sites keep on showing:

> Your browser's cookie functionality is turned off. Please turn it on. [?]

but every I perform the prescribed steps, Chrome doesn't keep the configuration!

**update**: I've deleted `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences` and restarted with a clean state. Now it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current development channel version has a problem with saving cookie settings and it's a know bug.

From the official Google Chrome Release blog [here](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/):

> Known Issues
>   Linux: Crash when editing a bookmark in the bookmark manager (Issue: 35438)
>   All: Chrome doesn't show popup blocker bubble (Issue: 35594)
>   **Mac/Linux: Can't save cookie settings (Issue: 35307)**

Comment: For me at least, the problem with the dev version is not saving the cookie settings, it's the actual cookie handling, and only (ironically) with Google's sites - Gmail/Reader/Voice/etc.  I didn't have cookie problems on any other sites.

I.E. before upgrading to that version, cookies on their sites were working fine.  Upgrade (w/o changing any settings) and suddenly google's site (but nobody else's) starts giving the error that I have cookies turned off.  (Which is demonstrably false, because if you look at the cookies you can see they are there)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I tried deleting all cookies/cache/etc and nothing worked for me.  I finally reverted to the beta version and its working fine now.